# Eclipse SWT Shell : getBounds() seems to return false coordinates

Tags: swt, jface, awtrobot

I tried the following to move the mouse pointer to the upper left corner of my shell (tested on Windows 10):

```java
// get shell's coordinates
int x = shell.getBounds().x;
int y = shell.getBounds().y;
// move the cursor
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(x, y);
```

But unfortunately this results in the placement of the mouse outside (left from and above the upper left corner) of the shell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to use `Display::setCursorLocation` to see where SWT would place the cursor? `Robot` is AWT API and may have a different view on the coordinate system.

Comment: BTW, if UI tests are on your mind, SWTBot may help: https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann : I followed your advice and yes, there is indeed a difference between the SWT and AWT coordinates.Unlike `robot::mouseMove`, `Display::setCursorLocation` sets the mouse to the upper left corner of the shell although both use the same x and y values.